# Create a listening stuck at listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am using `Bluetooth` API of android. I am here creating client-server connection using `BluetoothServerSocket` & `BluetoothSocket` but my program stuck at the certain point.

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery find a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Device Name: " + mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " Address: " + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress());
            new AcceptThread().start();
        }
    }
};

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothServerSocket mBluetoothServerSocket ;
    public AcceptThread() {
        try {
            mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while(true) {
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if(mBluetoothSocket != null) {
                // transfer the data here
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Socket is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                try {
                    // close the connection to stop to listen any connection now
                    mBluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch(IOException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my program stuck

```
mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
```

I could not catch why it getting stuck at this point, Any idea to you for this ?

Comment: Are you sure the thread is stopped at that line? That just creates a socket and returns, there is no blocking. You're not logging too much so I think it's highly probable that your code is waiting in the accept() call. Use the debugger and more logging to figure it out. We can't do much about it.

Comment: Yes I tested it. It does not goes in the run method.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the thread that stops in that method? Just start the app in debug mode and pause the execution when it stalls. Basic debugging.

Comment: Yes I debug it and see it stuck on `mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));`

Comment: What are the stack frames inside? Can you add the full trace to the question?

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is unclear whether your application is a client or server or both. For writing bluetooth client-server applications, android phone at any instance plays a single role of server or a client. If your phone is server, then you need to listen for connections from other bluetooth devices using method listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(). Then use accept() to complete the connection.

In case android phone acts as client, it will initiate a bluetooth connection to other devices. For such scenario, your broadcast receiver is needed. We need to scan for available bluetooth devices with startDiscovery() method. Your broadcast receiver's onReceive() is called when a new bluetooth device is found. To connect to this found device, call createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() with desired UUID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is BlueToothServer demo where it should execute run method once and accept the connection once it is required to setup client connection and run that code infintely. but in my case it stuck here `mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BT_SERVER", UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"));
` which is completely wrong. I don't know the reason that why I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious but did you instantiate your BluetoothAdapter? Accept Thread uses the adapter without intializing it.

```
myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Answer (score 0):

While listening, set the discovery name to a specific value then used `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord` method in broadcast receiver.

```
private class AcceptTask extends AsyncTask<UUID,Void,BluetoothSocket> {

    @Override
    protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(UUID... params) {
        String name = mBtAdapter.getName();
        try {
            //While listening, set the discovery name to a specific value
            mBtAdapter.setName(SEARCH_NAME);
            BluetoothServerSocket socket = mBtAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BluetoothRecipe", params[0]);
            BluetoothSocket connected = socket.accept();

            //Reset the BT adapter name
            mBtAdapter.setName(name);
            return connected;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mBtAdapter.setName(name);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        if(socket == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBtSocket = socket;
        ConnectedTask task = new ConnectedTask();
        task.execute(mBtSocket);
    }

}
// End
```